# How to get rdd after run rdd.map function on Spark (How to use rdd.insertInto)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-spark

I am using spark to process data. But I don't know how to save new data to Hive

I load rdd from Hive then run map function to cleanup the data.

```
result = myRdd.map(lambda x: cleanup(x))
```

I want to save the result to new table in Hive. so I use

```
result.insertInto("newTable", True)
```

I get the Error: `'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'insertInto'`

How do I convert result to rdd to use `insertInto` function? I also want to know there is other way to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for it

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
srdd = sqlCtx.inferSchema(result)
```

Now I can use

```
srdd.insertInto("newTable", True)
```